# Implementing chat in Django application

Tags: django, chat, live, channel

I am a beginner in Django and I am trying to implement chatting in my Django app. I got 3 questions on how to approach this. 
1. I see that people recommend to do this using Django Channels but what are the downsides to just using a database?
2. The tutorials on Channels seem to be on how to create a chat room. However I actually want the chat to be not in rooms but rather between users (I am using the default User model btw). Can anyone recommend a tutorial on how to do that?
3. In the official Django documentation JS is used too but I am not too familiar with it. So how much JS do I need to know to implement the chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The downside of using a database is that you would need to constantly ask the database to see if there is a new message if you're concerned with real-time chat. If it's something like an email where the sent messages are checked by the other user by refreshing page or sending a request, using a database based system would work I think even better.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any ideas on the other 2 questions?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to use data channels but I don't think it would involve a deep javascript knowledge since you only need to use some library functions.